# android garbage collection on anonymous objects

Tags: android, garbage-collection

I have the following snippet of code:

```
ArrayList<GameObject> gameObjectList = new ArrayList<GameObject>();

public void init(){
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        loadedOjectList.add(new GameObject());
    }
}
```

Now say I want to leave the activity or maybe load a new level in my game. Would writing `loadedObjectList.clear()` be sufficient to make the 10 objects be eligible for garbage collection? I had something similar to this and whenever I would progress through the levels my game would start slowing down because I'm guessing the objects still exist somewhere. Any ideas?

Comment: In theory it should, but keep in mind, that the capacity does not change, thus leaving the backing array's size unchanged. Also GC only kicks in if needed.

Comment: After the arraylist has been cleared, if I were to call init() a second time then would the add() method put the object at index 0 to 9 or would it start at index 10 to 19?

Comment: The size will be reported as 0 and all new objects will be added from indexes beginning with 0. Just the backing array is not removed, just nulled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of Course the objects will be Garbage Collected because the references get nullified. So the Objects are good to be collected...